# asp net mvc sql server problem

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

how do i implement the ORM for my existing database tables ( that resides on the sql server )
to fit with asp net mvc3 ?

i tried to create all the table properties (pocos) by hand and build and it wont map it properly, i hope someone can point me in the right direction.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using entity framework, build you entities based off of the current database.  When you start a new entity in your project you are asked if you want to build from a current database or empty.

Answer (score 0):

i saw the answer
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/08/03/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database.aspx

basically the steps when building an asp mvc using an existing database

1. install your asp mvc3 on your vs2010
2. download & install the Entity Framework 4 CTP 5
3. and follow the instruction from http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-model-classes-with-the-entity-framework-cs to build a set of models from your existing database

:)

thanks a lot @Adam & @Brett

more power!

Answer (score 0):

Check Asp.net
theres a lot of tutorial about asp.net mvc to start of.. you can start at storefront or nerdinner.

[Asp.net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc)
Regards.